# Pandas Panel from Dict of Dataframes Returns NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, nan

I have a group of DataFrames that I'm trying to turn into a Panel.
Here is my code:

```
# OPEN THE FILES INTO DATAFRAMES
filenames = ['Yahoo_2016-01-17.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-01-18.csv',
    'Yahoo_2016-01-19.csv','Yahoo_2016-01-23.csv','Yahoo_2016-01-27.csv',     
    'Yahoo_2016-02-05.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-02-06.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-02-09.csv',     
    'Yahoo_2016-02-11.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-02-13.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-02-15.csv', 
    'Yahoo_2016-02-16.csv', 'Yahoo_2016-02-29.csv']

dates = np.array(['2016-01-17', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-19', '2016-01-23', 
    '2016-01-27', '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06','2016-02-09', 
    '2016-02-11', '2016-02-13', '2016-02-15', '2016-02-16',
    '2016-02-29']).astype('datetime64[D]')

filepath = '/Users/RickS/Documents/Investing/Stock_files/GENERAL/'

dfs = [pd.read_csv(filepath+f) for f in filenames]

# Panel not working...
panel = pd.Panel(dict([(date, df) for date in dates for df in dfs]))
panel.swapaxes('major','minor')
```

However when I try to read the panel, all the values in each dataframe have turned into NaNs:

[image: Data is NaNs]

When I look at the dataframes individually they all look fine.
Here is one of the csv files that gets imported into df:
[example_csv_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fIUnohbY5IYVZFWS1rcmNTSVE/view?usp=sharing)

One thing to note that may (or may not) be important is that the dtypes for each dataframe are not all the same:

```
In [24]: dfs[1].dtypes
Out[24]: 
Name                          object
Symbol                        object
Previous_Close               float64
Average_Daily_Volume           int64
Change_&_Percent_Change       object
Earnings/Share               float64
EPS_Estimate_Current_Year    float64
EPS_Estimate_Next_Quarter    float64
EPS_Estimate_Next_Year       float64
52-week_Low                  float64
52-week_High                 float64
EBITDA                        object
200-day_Moving_Average       float64
P/E_Ratio                    float64
PEG_Ratio                    float64
Short_Ratio                  float64
1_yr_Target_Price            float64
52-week_Range                 object
Date                          object
dtype: object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting! It would be easier to help you if your example was self contained -- if you provided sample data that produces the same problem. this site explains it better: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Without actual data, we cannot reproduce. There is an issue with your list comprehension wrapped in `dict()` that I almost posted an answer but in all my trials, I cannot recreate the all NaNs. Are your `dates` and `filenames` the same length? Also, save this to a dictionary, `dict([(date, df) for date in dates for df in dfs])` and output its content. Do you see NaNs?

Comment: I edited the question to include more detail including more complete code and one of the csv files that is read as a dataframe.  I tested the dictionary defined above -- dict([(date, df) for date in dates for df in dfs]) -- and results are fine (all data is there). The length of both 'dates' and 'filenames' is 13.

Comment: Even though the columns aren't the same within a DataFrame, are they the same between the DataFrames? i.e. do they all have the same columns?

Comment: yes they are all the same between dataframes

Comment: The problem in my situation was I was adding a new row to each dataframe in my panel and was setting the index to `datetime.today()`. However, because I was assigning in a loop the `datetime.today()` was different in every loop. So each df had rows for every timestamp across all dfs in the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for empty panel with all NaNs is your `dates` numpy array currently  stored as `datetime64` types. Apparently, the pandas panel object does not work well with underlying dictionary keys.

Simply remove the `astype` or even use a list or tuple which will render dates as string keys. But since dictionary keys are measured through days, each will be unique for your panel needs.

```
dates = np.array(['2016-01-17', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-19', '2016-01-23', 
                  '2016-01-27', '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06','2016-02-09', 
                  '2016-02-11', '2016-02-13', '2016-02-15', '2016-02-16',
                  '2016-02-29'])

dates = ['2016-01-17', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-19', '2016-01-23', 
         '2016-01-27', '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06','2016-02-09', 
         '2016-02-11', '2016-02-13', '2016-02-15', '2016-02-16',
         '2016-02-29']
```

However, this brings my earlier find. Currently, the list comprehension within the `dict()` function will return a panel of only the **last** data frame, repeated 13 times. Reason being the list comprehension below returns a total combination set between the `dfs` list and `dates` array with a length equal to the product of both collections: 13 X 13 (i.e., cross join/cartesian join). Output below to see:

```
[(date, df) for date in dates for df in dfs]
```

Once you apply `dict()` to above, you force the 13 unique `dates` to carry the value of last `df`, essentially pulling in the last *combination pairing*.

Consider using `zip()` to iterate over each item of both collections together:

```
dfDict = {}
for f,d in zip(filenames, dates):    
    dfDict[d] = pd.read_csv(filepath+f)    

panel = pd.Panel(dfDict)
```

Or the shorter:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filepath+f) for f in filenames] 
panel = pd.Panel(dict([i for i in zip(dates, dfs)]))
```